# Linq and choosing a default value if query is empty without checking size

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Instead of checking if the original query has any items, can this be simplified at all?  I hate doing this type of check and assign a default value after this type of check.

By the way this is an entity framework query, so it needs to be a part of the entire query.

```
LogoId = (from t in a.Event.Assets
          where t.Type == EventAssetType.Logo
          select t.AssetId).Any() ? (from t in a.Event.Assets
                                     where t.Type == EventAssetType.Logo
                                     select t.AssetId).FirstOrDefault() : (a.Event.Organization != null && a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset != null ? a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset.AssetId : 0),
```

Comment: What about DefaultIfEmpty()?

Comment: What about it?  That would give 0 correct.

Comment: You can put whatever value you want inside the parenthesis ... although I wish you could put a Func to fetch the value.  Its a little-known LINQ operator that may help here.

Comment: @MikeFlynn It accepts the default value *as an argument*.

Comment: Having a couple of if guard-clauses would make this code much simpler, if not [safer](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/). But as @insta wrote, [this overload of `DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DefaultIfEmpty has an overload that takes a parameter.

```
LogoId = (from t in a.Event.Assets
      where t.Type == EventAssetType.Logo
      select t.AssetId)
.DefaultIfEmpty((a.Event.Organization != null && a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset != null ? a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset.AssetId : 0)).First();
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the simpler you can do is

```
LogoId = from t in a.Event.Assets
         where t.Type == EventAssetType.Logo
         select t.AssetId).FirstOrDefault();

if (LogoId == 0) 
{
    LogoId = a.Event.Organization != null && a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset != null 
        ? a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset.AssetId : 0;
}
```

Not sure if is much more simple that your code but maybe is more readable.

Comment: I want to do this in a linq query

Comment: @Mike Flynn: I'm using linq everywhere I can, where else you would like to see linq?

Comment: Most readable IMO.  Will prevent the person debugging your code from stabbing you for abusing the ternary operator.

Comment: The LogoId is in a larger query, so doing a check of LogoId == 0 is out of the question.  I wouldnt even of posted this question if I could of done it this way.

Comment: @Mike Flynn: Ok, sorry. I'm not a wizard... I answered the question based on the information I see. It is full of people asking how to write something in a single line even when that single line would contain 700 method call and all kind of stuff. Just because they think one line is "better".

Answer (score 2):

Use `??` operator:

```
(from t in a.Event.Assets
          where t.Type == EventAssetType.Logo
          select new Nullable<int>(t.AssetId)).FirstOrDefault() ??  (a.Event.Organization != null && a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset != null ? a.Event.Organization.OrganizationAsset.AssetId : 0)
```

Comment: The default value is 0, so NULL will never be hit.

Comment: If you cast `t.AssetId` to a nullable type (i.e. `(long?)`), then it will work fine.

Comment: I don't want my LogoId to be nullable, which it looks like it needs to be

Comment: @MikeFlynn: it doesn't have to be, you simply cast it to a nullable value to trick the result of the first select to be nullable.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Applying the null coalescing operator to a `Nullable` and using a non-nullable type for the second operand results in a non-nullable type, not a nullable type, so the entire expression ends up being non-nullable, not nullable.

Comment: This I believe worked but not as clean as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MikeFlynn That's right, accepted answer is the best answer.